# Visual Studio 2015 UWP Error: Microsoft.VCLibs not found

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2015

I create a UWP project with Visual Studio 2015 and from from one moment to another I get, when I open my project this error:

> The SDK "SQLite.UAP.2015, Version=3.9.2" depends on the following
>   SDK(s) "Microsoft.VCLibs, version=14.0", which have not been added to
>   the project or were not found. Please ensure that you add these
>   dependencies to your project or you may experience runtime issues. You
>   can add dependencies to your project through the Reference Manager.

In my Project I use

- SQLite.UAP from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html
- SQLite.Net-PCL from NuGet

I updated all possible over "Tools->Extensions and Updates"

I don't change anything special on my code only some Buttons and Textlines.

I don't find a solution for this problem.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? I'm facing the same warning.

Comment: I found the Error in the Error List, when i scrolled down. (See answer below). It was an Error in the Code.

Comment: @alfah I fixed this warning when I added reference to "Visual C++ 2015 Runtime..." http://1drv.ms/1LlojMN

Comment: @kubakista It did solve the problem!! Why exactly is that reference required?

Comment: @alfah To be honest I have no idea. There must be some kind of dependencies between SQLite and this library because of C++ but who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the Error was in the code. I added to the Page sector in the XAML file:

```
Loaded="Page_Loaded"
```

but forgot to add to the .cs File the Methode:

```
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in your References for the project, you should see under the Universal Windows>>Extensions an option to select for Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows 14.0.

Try adding that reference to your project.

If you do not see that option you will need to add it using the tools get tools and features from the visual studio menu. You can select Individual components and locate the missing SDK that you need.